# Updating MDB file from it's MDE

Tags: ms-access

I had created a MDE file from a MDB file. Now i want to use MDE file to enter/update any field on my table and store data in it. I just want that whatever i update in my MDE file should automatically update my parent MDB file. Please help me with steps. I tried link manager but it isn't working. Please help me with it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of your MDB.

Then run the wizard to *split a database* into frontend and backend.

Finally, create an MDE of the frontend.

Now both the MDE and the MDB will share the same backend.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply! I tried doing the same and i followed these steps:
1. Created a copy of MDB file 
2. Run access database and split the database (appeneded wiith _be)
3. Created a "make a MDE" file and entered data into it. Now when i closed my MDE file and opened the MBD file, the MDB file was not updated with data i entered in MDE file...... Also while splliting the database , i encountered " cannot lock ....table it is being used by other user" however there was no open table i checked. I am very new to MS access .sorry for new doubts

Comment: The split wizard normally works right away, so probably something else is going on. Try again.